# bash - hash binary contents of variable without creating a file

Tags: linux, bash, curl, hash, md5sum

I am trying to obtain the hash of the contents stored in a variable created from a curl statement without outputting the curl into a file.

Basically I am trying to avoid:

```
curl website.com/file.exe >> tempfile.bin
md5sum tempfile.bin
```

The above provides the correct md5 hash. My approach (below) seemed to have work when testing plain text files, however when I attempted to download a binary and save it to a variable the hash was different than when I saved it to a file.

My attempt:

```
binary=$(curl website.com/file.exe)
echo $binary | md5sum
```

I think I may be missing a flag, or perhaps echo may not be the best way to do it. The important part of this challenge is not writing a file to disk, yet achieving the same md5 hash as if it were written to disk.

Comment: Does `echo -n` and quoting the variable help?

Comment: sadly -n nor -e nor the combo works.

Comment: @Onitsoga You most certainly don't want `-e`. Did you quote the variable?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that did not work :(

Comment: @Biffen I did with and without with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To also skip the step of using a temp variable, you can use process substitution:

```
md5sum <(curl website.com/file.exe)
```

or pipe to `md5sum` directly:

```
curl website.com/file.exe | md5sum
```

Comment: Don't really need a process substitution. `curl | md5sum` would do as well (and more portable too).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Added!

Comment: This seemed to work perfectly! Haha and its so simple!

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention I would need to preserve the binary in the variable for later use. So I still need to rely on an echo?

Comment: `var=$(curl ...; echo x); var=${var%x}`. The command substitution will strip any trailing newlines from the output of the command, so you need a sentinel value to ensure you don't lose any final bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The bash shell doesn't handle raw binary data well, as you've experienced.  To accomplish your goal, you will need to encode the file contents into a text format when you read them into the bash variable, and decode them when you write them out.

For instance, if you have the base64 tool, you can use it to re-implement your example like this:

```
encoded=$(curl website.com/file.exe | base64)
echo "$encoded" | base64 --decode | md5sum
```

If you later want to save the data to a file named $output, you could do it like this:

```
echo "$encoded" | base64 --decode -o "$output"
```

Comment: If this works this is more along the lines of what I need. However when I run this I receive the error "base64: invalid input"

Comment: After a few more tries this worked perfectly! Thanks! I had to echo the variable in quotes. So for my example:

`binary=$(curl website.com/file.exe | base64);
echo "$binary" | base64 --decode | md5sum` This gave me the propper md5sum

Comment: Sorry about that! I've updated the answer to include the quotes.